# How to view bootups extending 1 month

Tags: 12.04, boot, command-line, log

I am trying to view a log of previous bootups. The following command does exactly what I want it to do

```
last -x | grep shutdown
```

with the only limitation being that it only displays events within the current month. Being November 6, this gives me only 6 days to see.

I would like to view events from say, October 30th or earlier. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last` reads the file `/var/log/wtmp`, but you can point it to another file. In your case that would be `/var/log/wtmp.1`.

So, the modified command that you need to use is

```
last -x -f /var/log/wtmp.1 | grep shutdown
```

Comment: This is awesome! thank you. my one question is this: when using my initial command, i see 1 shutdown on Nov. 4, 4 from Nov. 2, and 2 from Nov. 1.

when using your command, it starts with the 2 of Nov. 1. Just wondering if it only removed those 5 entries, or if there are others missing as well, and why

Comment: I don't really know, I have [the same output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13123318/)... But I'm on 14.04! Maybe that means something (maybe a bug in 12.04, then corrected?)

Comment: could be because you used *last -x -f /var/log/wtmp | grep shutdown* instead of *last -x -f /var/log/wtmp.1 | grep shutdown*?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I misinterpreted what you wrote. In principle, there should be no intersection at all with the two commands.

Comment: sorry, it was a confusing comment. I'll try to upload the output of the commands later to show what i mean